# Can I get Argentina Tourist Visa in Thailand if I am Nepalese passport holder?

Tags: visas, thailand, argentina, bolivia

I am a nepalese passport holder and am planning a trip to Argentina in April. Unfortunately we don't have an embassy or consulate for Argentina in Nepal. We have to go through Embassy of Argentina in New Delhi. I was wondering if I could go to Bangkok and get a visa from the embassy of Argentina in Bangkok rather than going to New Delhi. Is it possible to do that?

However as a Nepalese passport holder, I read that we get visa on arrival to Bolovia. I was also thinking flying into Bolovia and obtain tourist visa in Bolovia. Is that a better idea?

Will it help me to get Argentina  tourist visa if I have a valid Schengen visa in my passport?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Henning.Seems like there is no other way than going to Delhi :) .

Answer (score 7):

Argentina appears to follow the common rule that you *must* apply for a visa at the consulate that covers the area/country **where you live**.

Your *nationality* determines whether you need a visa at all or not, but once you have determined that you do need a visa, it is your *residence* that governs where to apply.

You don't write where you live, but if you live in Nepal it looks like the embassy in New Delhi is where you need to go to interview to get an Argentine visa.

The practical reason for this rule is that one part of considering your application is to determine whether you're likely to leave Argentina after your trip and return to Nepal. To this end you will need to demonstrate convincing ties to Nepal that would motivate you to go back -- and the consular officers in New Delhi will be the ones with training and experience in evaluating ties to Nepal and with the kinds of documentation that is reasonably available to Nepal residents. Those in Bangkok won't have this experience, so they won't be able to give your application as meaningful an evaluation.

---

It seems to be correct that as a Nepalese citizen you can get visa-on-arrival in Bolivia. However, of course, that would enable you to visit Bolivia, not to go to Argentina. Whether you think this convenience makes it worthwhile for you to change your vacation plans so you visit Bolivia instead of Argentina, is something only you can decide.

A Schengen visa will probably not be relevant in either case -- except that eyebrows will be raised if your entry/exit stamps show that you overstayed it.

Comment: Schengen visa won't probably matter for Argentina, but I found some countries allowing visa-free entry if you hold a US/Schengen visa (most likely because those visas are difficult to get compared to others) and they immediately trust you to grant limited visa-free entry.

Comment: Yes,I was thinking if Schengen visa could help.Thank you for your reply :)